# Multiple, sequential presses of AHK key combination to paste special in Word or PowerPoint

Tags: ms-word, powerpoint, autohotkey, clipboard, paste

I use an AHK script to speed up the Paste Special (plain text) command in Microsoft Word and PowerPoint.  I press LCtrl + LShift + v to initiate the paste and here is the script:

```
#NoTrayIcon
^+v::   ; work with the clipboard: paste clipboard content as plain text
ClipboardOld := ClipboardAll  ;save original clipboard contents
Clipboard = %Clipboard%  ;store plain text from clipboard to clipboard
Send ^v  ;send the Ctrl+V command
Sleep, 250  ;give some time to finish paste (before restoring clipboard)
Clipboard := ClipboardOld  ;restore the original clipboard contents
ClipboardOld =  ;clear temporary variable (potentially contains large data)
Return
```

This works great unless I do this: I do the paste with LCtrl + LShift + v, release the 'v' key, but do not release the LCtrl or LShift buttons, because I want to do the Paste Special again. Then, while the LCtrl and LShift keys are depressed, I press the 'v' key again to do another Paste Special.  Instead of pasting the plain text, it simply types the 'v' letter.

I would like to be able to do the Paste Special multiple times sequentially without having to release the LCtrl and LShift keys.  Is this possible?

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer at the AutoHotKey forums: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/

Comment: Your `Send` command releases the modifiers, so that's the problem you need to fix. I don't have time to write an answer right now, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Works fine here. I don't have to release the LCtrl and LShift keys for repeating the Paste Special.